# Django: after I render a template from a view with dynamic data the template stays static and does not change when data is added to the database

Tags: django, dynamic-data

In my views.py I have this code

```
from .forms import *
from students.models import Student
from classes.models import Class
from venues.models import Venue
from courses.models import Course
from registrations.models import Registration

class Test(View):
    template_name = "test.html"
    context = {}
    data_summary = {
        "total_students": Student.objects.all().count(),
        "total_classes": Class.objects.all().count(),
        "total_courses": Course.objects.all().count(),
        "total_registrations": Registration.objects.all().count(),
    }

    def get(self,*args, **kwargs):
        return render(self.request,self.template_name,self.data_summary)
```

In my test.html  I have this:

```
<...snip ...>
        <h3> Totals: </h3>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
           <label style="color: Blue; font-size:24"> Students: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
          {% if total_students %}
```

<... snip ...>

The template renders very nicely but if I update my database and add another student and or class and reload my page the data in my dictionary does not update.

I am at a loss why the data doesn't update.   I am now banging my head and not in the 70's good way either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `data_summary` is a class attribute, and is created when the `Test` class is declared the first time (on module load).

you can move it to the `get` method, and be assured that the database calls happen whenever the page `get` happens

```
def get(self,*args, **kwargs):
    data_summary = {
    "total_students": Student.objects.all().count(),
    "total_classes": Class.objects.all().count(),
    "total_courses": Course.objects.all().count(),
    "total_registrations": Registration.objects.all().count(),
    }
    return render(self.request,self.template_name,data_summary)
```

Comment: Now that it has been explained it makes perfect sense.   Thank-you.